# How can I move text decoration underline property so that It's not break text

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

As I am using "Lato Regular 900" font family and it breaks the "text-decoration:underline" property when I hover the text. Is there any solution to move the underline property from bottom side. So that it not break the text underline.
As seen pic [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RN8s0.png)

And I want like this pic
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsZ3C.png)

And my html code is`

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
    
a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
   font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a href='' onmouseover>UI/UX DESIGNING</a>
</body>
</html>
```

`

Comment: use bottom border instead

Comment: Your code is running fine here but if it is not working at your end then you can use border-bottom on hover as suggested above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change this behavior to force the underline/overline to go through the character by setting text-decoration-skip-ink to none.

```css
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-skip-ink: none;
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer, probably the best and most correct one, but is not supported on some popular browsers unfortunately :(

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can I move it down by any css property

Comment: No, We can't control text decorate line's movement using CSS only.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it working fine in all browsers ?

Answer (score 2):

use `text-underline-position: under;`

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
    
a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  text-underline-position:under;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration:underline;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a href='' onmouseover>UI/UX DESIGNING</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please check @anubhav
use border-bottom

Comment: I am aware of that. Is this done by text-decoration property

Comment: Now check once @anubhav

Comment: **text-underline-position: under;** use this

Answer (score 0):

**1st solution:**

Please try using `border-bottom` property css and you can apply padding to `a` tag.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
      a:link {
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        padding: 2px;
      }
      a:hover {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #0b3a70;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href='' onmouseover>UI/UX DESIGNING</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

**2nd solution:**

Please try using `text-underline-position` property on `a` tag on hover.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
      a:link {
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
      }
      a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
        text-underline-position: under;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href='' onmouseover>UI/UX DESIGNING</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am aware of that. Is this done by text-decoration property

Comment: Yes, you can do that. I updated my answer. Please check now.